# Ansible timestamp which is the same for all nodes during the whole play

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I would like to have a timestamp variable, which is the same across across all hosts.
(I include this in the name of directories: it must be the same on all hosts)

My initial idea was to add a declaration into **group_vars/all.yml**, since that
has a relatively high precedence and should be shared.

**group_vars/all.yml**:

```
my_timestamp: "{{ ansible_date_time.date }}{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}{{ ansible_date_time.second }}"
```

When tried, the values were different across hosts, making my directory structure inconsistent.
I suspect this is because the variable is only evaluated lazily, when the referred `ansible_date_time` object already has a different value on each host, depending on the exact moment execution reaches the variable reference and resolves the value.

The same issue happens when I try to `set_fact` in my playbook, at the very beginning.

**site.yml:**

```
---
# This playbook performs the deployment

- name: Prepare playbook settings
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Generate my timestamp
      set_fact:
        my_timestamp: "{{ ansible_date_time.date }}{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}{{ ansible_date_time.second }}"
```

The question is: how could I set a constant, shared timestamp, which is the same on all nodes during the whole execution of a playbook? What would be the *clean* Ansible way of generating a consistent, constant time-stamp? Without passing as a command line argument, printing to a file and the reading back the value etc.

I am on Ansible 2.9.23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base problem is that, using `set_fact` or not, you are parsing a value that is populated in the gathered facts for each host. Since the ssh connection to your targets will never happen at the exact same time, each host will have different values

The solution is to use one single timestamp from one single host for all of them. One way is to get it from the controller (`localhost`) but you can decide to get it elsewhere (i.e. the first host in your group during your deploy play using `set_facts` and `run_once` for example).

Here is the idea using the controller. Adapt to your own requirements

```yaml
---
- name: Make sure we gather facts from localhost
  hosts: localhost

- name: Make my actual deployment
  hosts: all

  vars:
    # declare timestamp using localhost values
    my_timestamp: >-
      {{
        hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time.date
      }}{{
        hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time.hour
      }}{{
        hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time.minute
      }}{{
        hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time.second
      }}      

  tasks:
    - name: Make sure timestamp value is the same everywhere
      debug:
        var: my_timestamp

    #... rest of your tasks...
```

Comment: My problem is that my playbook is broken down into smaller steps, where each calls one or more roles on a different set of nodes, while requiring the same variable value. A chicken-and-egg issue: the variable definition is deferred till playbook execution reaches that point, so it is different.

Comment: If you start with a first play as show above and get the same timestamp from localhost everytime, it will be the same. If in the worst case locahost is part of your other plays and you gather facts several times, you can set_fact once on localhost in the first play with a meaningfull var name and get that var from localhost elsewhere. It will not change thoughout the entire play.

Answer (score 3):

As the answer from @Zeitounator perfectly states, the variables are set per host, and at the time when its evaluated.

Another method that seems to work is to run the `set_fact` task once so its evaluated only once (`run_once`). Like:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:
    - name: save timestamp in var
      set_fact:
        my_timestamp: "{{ ansible_date_time.date }}{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}{{ ansible_date_time.second }}"
      run_once: true

    - name: show my_timestamp
      debug:
        var: my_timestamp
```

Since `my_timestamp` was set once, now the same timestamp would show up on every host.

Comment: I dont think this is correct.  ansible throws errors when trying to run this playbook - the first play doesn't even have a module listed

Comment: The example was to show how to `set_fact`, and that was the module to use in the task. It was a typo, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I took the suggestion from Zeitounator and ended up using an intermediate variable. While accepting Zeitounator's answer, I am posting a code sample for anyone interested in the actual solution.

```
---
# This playbook deploys our infrastrucure to each host type
- name: Prepare playbook settings
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Generate my timestamp
      set_fact:
        my_timestamp_local: "{{hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time.date}}{{ hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time.hour }}{{ hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time.minute }}{{hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time.second }}"
        cacheable: yes

    - name: Show generated timestamp
      debug:
        var: hostvars['localhost']['my_timestamp_local']


- name: apply common configuration to all nodes
  hosts: all
  vars:
    my_timestamp: "{{hostvars['localhost']['my_timestamp_local']}}"
  roles:
    - common

- name: apply foo node specific configuration
  hosts: foo_nodes
  vars:
    my_timestamp: "{{hostvars['localhost']['my_timestamp_local']}}"
  roles:
    - foo

- name: apply bar node specific configuration
  hosts: bar_nodes
  vars:
    my_timestamp: "{{hostvars['localhost']['my_timestamp_local']}}"
  roles:
    - bar
```